# How to install rjags when instalaltion is failing with undefined symbol: _ZN4jags7Console10setRNGnameERKNSt[...]

Tags: r, installation, jags, rjags

`install.packages("rjags")` and the `install.packages("rjags", configure.args="--enable-rpath")` recomended in `rjags`'s `INSTALL` fails with the following error:

```r
** testing if installed package can be loaded from temporary location
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rjags’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rjags', details:
  call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
  error: unable to load shared object '/<path to r libraries>/R_libraries/00LOCK-rjags/00new/rjags/libs/rjags.so':
  /<path to r libraries>/R_libraries/00LOCK-rjags/00new/rjags/libs/rjags.so: undefined symbol: _ZN4jags7Console10setRNGnameERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEj
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘<path to r libraries>/R_libraries/rjags’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rjags’ had non-zero exit status
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, this problem occures when using different compilers (/versions) for `JAGS` and `rjags`. After reading [these comments in the JAGS support forum](https://sourceforge.net/p/mcmc-jags/bugs/50/), I changed the compiler used to compile `rjags` to the system default that was presumably also used to build `JAGS` by unloading the `gcc/7.2.0` module I use (`module rm gcc/7.2.0`).